# How to apply searching on two table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have two table one is parentlist and childlist.

I have have to apply searching on this table by parentname and childname. I have provided my table structure for better understanding, I have to apply searching on two different field of with different field name.

Fieldname is `name` in parentlist table and `childname` in childlist table.

I want below output if I type `va` then parentlist and childlist record should come in that query like below example. With this `va` Srting i have a
parentname `varu123` and childname `varu123` so I want these two record  after executing the query.

This is the name of First table with fieldname

```
parentlist

............................................................
 id      name      mobilenumber  user_jid        email
............................................................
 1      varu123     123456         abc21        abc@gmail.com

 2      abhishesk   123456         abc21        def@gmail.com

 3      harsh        1234          def22        123@gmail.com
```

This is the name of Second table with fieldname

```
 childlist

..........................................
id user_id    childname     Shoolname  
...........................................
 1    1        ram            St.paul
 2    1        raj            St.xavier
 3    2        varu123        St.paul
 4    2        arun           St.xavier
 5    3        kapil          St.paul
 6    3        kamal          St.xavier
```

I want this output:  .

```
........................................................................................................
     id      name      mobilenumber  user_jid        email            childname        Shoolname
    ..........................................................................................................
     1      varu123     123456         abc21        abc@gmail.com       ram,raj         St.paul,St.xavier

     2      abhishesk   123456        abc21        def@gmail.com        varu123,arun    St.paul,St.xavier
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? SO is **not a free coding service**

Answer (score 1):

```
select pl.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cl.childname), GROUP_CONCAT(cl.Shoolname)
from parentlist as pl
inner join childlist as cl on pl.id=cl.user_id
where pl.name like '%va%' or cl.childname like '%va%'
```

Comment: This query only gives me the record of abhishek if i type varu123 i want the record of both varu123 and abhishek.one is a parentname and another is a childname.

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `inner join` or where :-

```
select * from parentlist inner join 
childlist on parentlist.id=childlist.user_id 
where childname='varu123' or parentlist.name='varu123'
```

use MySQL `inner join` or like :-

```
select * from parentlist inner join 
childlist on parentlist.id=childlist.user_id 
where childname like '%varu123%' or parentlist.name like '%varu123%'
```

Comment: This query is litile bit right but not the exact what i want it gives me
abhishek  123456    abc21   varu123
varu123     123456    abc21   raj
varu123     123456    abc21   ram

For detail refer my o/p 

in this one childname is missing or parent abhishek in second record varu123 comes twice i want this
abhishek  123456    abc21   varu123,arun
varu123     123456    abc21   raj,ram

Comment: select *,GROUP_CONCAT(childname), GROUP_CONCAT(Shoolname) from parentlist inner join 
childlist on parentlist.id=childlist.user_id 
where childname like '%varu123%' or parentlist.name like '%varu123%' group by user_id

Comment: try this query @varunjoshi

Comment: Hi rahautos, In this query it is not giving me the second childname of abhishek which is arun it gives me only varu123 and i want varu123,arun otherwise the query was right .

Comment: select *,GROUP_CONCAT(childname), GROUP_CONCAT(Shoolname) from parentlist inner join childlist on parentlist.id=childlist.user_id where user_id in (select user_id from parentlist inner join childlist on parentlist.id=childlist.user_id where childname like '%varu123%' or parentlist.name like '%varu123%' group by user_id) group by user_id

Comment: try this query @varunjoshi

Comment: Thanku so much rahutos this is very useful for me